# Redirect to login page on unaothorized response from the server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I use the following code in middle-ware:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(context =>
            {
                var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

                if (response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized ||
                    response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                    response.Redirect("/SampleController/LoginUserAction");

                return Task.CompletedTask;

            });
```

However, it works only it authentication is used on the client, but this is not needed because I already handle all autnetication on the server.  I simply want to redirect any action to a login page when 401 or 403 is received from the server, like this:

```
if ((int)result.StatusCode == 401 || (int)result.StatusCode == 403)
        return RedirectToAction("LoginUserAction", "SampleController");
```

but I don't want to repetitively call this from each controller action where the response is received. I want to write one code in Startup that will be called automatically whenever unauthorized response is received, similarly like one written above.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the login path in [ConfigureServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

so the unauthorized requests will redirect to the login page.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.Cookie.Name = "YourAppCookieName";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    // ReturnUrlParameter requires 
    //using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
    options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

According to docs, ConfigureApplicationCookie **must be** called after calling AddIdentity or AddDefaultIdentity.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a base controller that your other controllers inherit from then override the `OnActionExecuted` method to check the status code and redirect wherever necessary like so:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{ 
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if(context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 403)
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Sample",
                action = "LoginUserAction"
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

and all other controllers which should share this behavior would inherit from the `BaseController` as follows:

```
public class SampleController : BaseController
{
     //more here
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, however, here the status code will never be 403 or 401 because client does not use any authentication. I need to somehow get server's Response in here to be checked.